# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication7.Models.HesapTemel]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am having a problem running this project : i have a table for my products and in the same page i can to press on "add" button and i will have a small window to add my new product .. this is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    CountingEntities hsb = new CountingEntities();

    public ActionResult ProductTable()
    {

        var product = hsb.HesapTemels.ToList();

        List<HesapTemel> yardimci = hsb.HesapTemels.ToList();
        ViewBag.Funds = yardimci;
        return View(product);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProductTable(HesapTemel p)
    {
        try
        {
            HesapTemel _he = new HesapTemel();

            _he.HesapAdi = p.HesapAdi;
            _he.HesapKodu = p.HesapKodu;
            _he.HesaptipiID = p.HesaptipiID;
            hsb.HesapTemels.Add(_he);
            hsb.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("HesapTable", "Home");
          }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("an error happened" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
<div>
<a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bootstrapmodal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
    </span>Add
</a>
<div class="modal fade bootstrapmodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Partial("_partial.cshtml");
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>hesap kodu</th>
                <th>hesap adı</th>
                <th>hesap tipi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Funds)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ID</td>
                    <td>@item.HesapKodu</td>
                    <td>@item.HesapAdi</td>
                    <td>@item.Hesaptipi.Harf</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is my partial view :

```
@model WebApplication7.Models.HesapTemel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hesap kodu</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HesapKodu, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hesap adı</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.HesapAdi, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

when i am running this solution i have this error : 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication7.Models.HesapTemel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication7.Models.HesapTemel'.

Comment: Which line of code shows the error? What is the model type for main view?

Comment: its not showing any line error ! .. model type is the same with main view...the project is working when i am deleting my partial view and write the same code but as a main view .. but i want to make the "add product" in the same page without going to another link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ProductTable` action method is passing a list of `HesapTemels` objects to the view and i am assuming your main view is strongly typed to a collection of this same `HesapTemels` objects. Your partial view is strongly typed to a single instance of `HesapTemel`. In your main view, you are calling the Partial method without explcitly passing a model to it. If you do not pass a model , It will use the model passed to the parent view from this partial is called, hence using the collection of `HesapTemel` objects which was passed to the main view. The partial is expecting a single `HesapTemel` object to be passed to it and now it is getting a collection of it and that is the reason you are seeing the error.

The solution is to pass the correct data. Since the partial is expecting a single object of `HesapTemel`, you may loop through the collection in your main view and call the partial in the loop and pass each item of the looped collection.